# helm-ag vs helm-do-ag

Tags: helm, helm-ag

What are the differences between `helm-ag` and `helm-do-ag` from a user perspective? I see that `helm-do-ag` shows the results immediately and `helm-ag` not. But are there other differences and when is it better to use `helm-ag` instead of `helm-do-ag` and vice versa?

Comment: In `helm-ag` you can pass command line options to ag, for example to filter filenames with `-Gfilename pattern`. `helm-do-ag` doesn't seem to allow this.

Comment: Thanks. How about helm-do-grep-ag? What is different there?